# Removing an item from a BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, collections

How can an item be removed from a BlockingCollection? Which of the following is correct?

```
myBlockingCollection.Remove(Item);
```

or

```
myBlockingCollection.Take(Item);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't specify a particular item to be removed from a `BlockingCollection<T>`.

The `Take()` method removes an item from the underlying collection and returns the removed item.

The `TryTake(out T item)` method removes an item from the underlying collection and assigns the removed item to the `out` parameter. The method returns true if an item could be removed; otherwise, false.

The item which is removed depends on the underlying collection used by the `BlockingCollection<T>` - For example, `ConcurrentStack<T>` will have LIFO behavior and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` will have FIFO behavior.

Answer (score 5):

What about this code? - It's working but change the order of the collection. (And I didn't checked it in multi threads state).

```
public static bool Remove<T>(this BlockingCollection<T> self, T itemToRemove)
    {
        lock (self)
        {
            T comparedItem;
            var itemsList = new List<T>();
            do
            {
                var result = self.TryTake(out comparedItem);
                if (!result)
                    return false;
                if (!comparedItem.Equals(itemToRemove))
                {
                    itemsList.Add(comparedItem);
                }
            } while (!(comparedItem.Equals(itemToRemove)));
            Parallel.ForEach(itemsList, t => self.Add(t));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The trouble with this is none of the other methods on the collection are going to lock on self. For instance what happens if another thread adds a new item after you create itemsList.

Answer (score 2):

I think only TryTake() is an option? I can't find documention on the Remove() method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I think `TryTake(out item)` will work. Remove does not exist in BlockingCollection class and Take does not take item as parameter.

Comment: TryTake(out item) does not specify which item to remove like Remove(item) does. There is not equivalent.